# Parameter 0 of constructor in com.services required a bean of type 'com.repositories.repository' that could not be found

Tags: java, maven, spring-data-jpa, backend

`If I try to use a custom interface that extends JpaRepository the application can't run. Here's the error:

`

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.services.EquipeServices required a bean of type 'com.repositories.EquipeRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.repositories.EquipeRepository' in your configuration.`

When the repository is called in the 'EquipeServices.java' class, everything stops working and the application can't start.

Here's the complete **LOG ERROR**:

`Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'listaTimes' defined in file [/home/daniel/demo/target/classes/com/controllers/ListaTimes.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'equipeServices' defined in file [/home/daniel/demo/target/classes/com/services/EquipeServices.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.repositories.EquipeRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Here's the code:

**DemoApplication.java**

```java
package com;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.controllers", "com.services", "com.repositories", "com.entities"})
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        
    }
}
```

**EquipeRepository.java**

```java
package com.repositories;

import com.entities.Equipe;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

@Repository
public interface EquipeRepository extends JpaRepository<Equipe, UUID>{

    
}
```

**EquipeServies.java**

```java
package com.services;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.repositories.EquipeRepository;
import com.entities.Equipe;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class EquipeServices {
    
    EquipeRepository equipeRepository;

    public EquipeServices(EquipeRepository repository){
        this.equipeRepository = repository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Equipe> getAllUsers(){
        return equipeRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.teste</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2023.0.2</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>`
```

`

Comment: Try @EnableJpaRepositories("your repo package") in the main class.

Comment: It gave me two new Exceptions:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer 

and

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1cf4f579]

Comment: remove `@Repository` is not relevant because you already have extended from `JpaRepository` also in service class declare a field of `equipeRepository` as `private final`, remove `@ComponentScan` from your main class, Spring Boot automatically scan your packages and create beans if structure of your project meet the requirement(main class is placed in a root package above other packages.).

Comment: and also remove from your maven `javax.persistence` dependency, because you are using spring boot 3.1.2 and it work on `jakarta.persistence` and `javax.validation` the same think on it.